# printing uint16_t type

Tags: c, printf, uint16

I'm reading a file in binary mode this way:

```
fread(&pcap_header      ,sizeof(pcap_hdr_t      ),  1 , pFile);
fread(&pcaprec_header   ,sizeof(pcaprec_hdr_t   ),  1 , pFile);
fread(&ether_header     ,sizeof(ethernet_hdr_t  ),  1 , pFile);
fread(&ip_header        ,sizeof(ip_hdr_t        ),  1 , pFile);
fread(&tcp_header       ,sizeof(tcp_header_t    ),  1 , pFile);
fread(&modbus_header    ,sizeof(modbus_header_t ),  1 , pFile);
```

while all the variables above are defined as the type in the 'sizeof()' function next to it.
I'm trying to extract a specific part of the file and print it. the size of this part is 16 bit and it is defined like this:

```
uint16_t     ip_len;
```

inside the type 'ip_hdr_t'. I looked at WireShark and saw the real value of this 16 bits and it is 0x0034.

I tried a two things:

1. `printf("size of ip header: %hu\n", ip_header.ip_len);` which printed 13312 (as if the value of the bits is 0x3400)
2. divide the structure to two 8 bit variables:
   `uint8_t  ip_len;
   uint8_t   ip_len2;`
   and print it separately: 
       `printf("size of ip header:  %hu\n", ip_header.ip_len);
   printf("size of ip header:  %hu\n", ip_header.ip_len2);`

this time i recieved the output: size of ip header: 0 (0x00)
size of ip header: 52 (0x34)
which is the right answer.

my question is: what did go wrong in the first print?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) problem; your platform does not have the same endianness as the protocol you're using.  You need to exchange the order of the bytes.

If you're on a POSIX-compliant system, you can use the [`ntoh` family of functions](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl).

I'm not sure whether there's an equivalent for e.g. Windows.

Comment: Same functions are available on Win32: `ntohs` and `ntohl`.